# How to calculate Impression Share % with Adwords API?

Tags: google-ads-api

Search impression share is defined as:

> The impressions you’ve received on the Search Network divided by the
>   estimated number of impressions you were eligible to receive.

I can pull Impressions from the API, but what metric can I pull to get 'estimated number of impressions you were eligible to receive'?

I have looked thru the API documentation many times and can't find it, seems like I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can get that data with reports, like `CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT`, for example.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-performance-report#searchexactmatchimpressionshare

It is not that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, impression share is not pullable through API. It WAS there, but Google decided to remove this functionality - [see this AdWords blog post](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.cz/2013/01/adwords-api-reporting-impression-share.html).

Comment: The new column includes 'SearchImpressionShare' can that be pulled from the API? Or are none of the new Impression Share metric available via API?

Comment: As far as I know, no impressions-share metrics can are available via API.

Comment: did I answer your question or there is something more you need to know?

Comment: Turns out you can pull SearchImpressionShare via the API. So we can use that to calculate backwards.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out you can pull in Impressions, SearchImpressionShare, and to get the estimated # of impressions you were eligible to receive, you just go backwards and calculate for x.

So then you can take the impressions you’ve received on the Search Network divided by the estimated number of impressions you were eligible to receive (which we calculated) to get the Impression Share %.

Of course this number doesn't tell us anything new, but we needed to calculate it to be able to aggregate the percentage across several channels to see an estimate 'total share of voice'.